# Recording video without resetting the preview or stopping the MediaRecorder

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, android-mediarecorder

I am working on an application in which MediaRecorder record a video file for 5 second and then start recording again and continue. Videos being recorded should be of five second but what my problem is we need to stop the MediaRecorder and then prepare the MediaRecorder again and which cause a blink on the screen and also produce the start and stop sound.

What I want to achieve is media recorder keep recording 5 second video file but user should not get notice that video is being recorded and screen does not get reset.

Comment: have you ever solved this?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that best option for You will be using ffmpeg to record video all the time and just cut and save 5 sec. parts of the video. In that case You won't have to stop/start mediarecorder.